# Trigger on view in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a materialized view and a view which is just select * from materialized view. I want to have a trigger on the view, which will be executed after refreshing a materialized view. I tried with After insert or update trigger, but it seems it's not working. Is it possible to do this in Pgsql?

As an easy example (in reality i will not have test table in the same db ofc):

```
create table test(id integer primary key, sth integer);
create materialized view test_mv as select * from test;
create view test_mv_v as select * from test_mv;
create or replace function test_trig() returns trigger as $$ begin raise notice 'triggered'; return null;end;$$ language 'plpgsql';
create trigger test after insert or update on test_mv_v for each statement execute procedure test_trig();
```

Comment: Refreshing a materialized view does not trigger `INSERT` neither `UPDATE` triggers. Those triggered only when someone tries to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the materialized view itself (think of updatable views) -- `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` might get (eventually) an event-trigger, but [right now (as of 9.6) that doesn't supported either](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html).

Comment: Thx, do You think is there some workaround for it? If not I think I'll just use pg_cron, which maybe isn't perfect but will work for me.

Comment: you could write a function (stored procedure) which does the refresh & all other custom action(s) you would write into that trigger. If you refresh the MV through that function only, you can achieve the same thing. Cron is an option too, but then your custom action(s) will be executed with a delay.